# how Python Regex work for an expression like (\w+) vs (\w.+)

Tags: python, regex

Please consider the following example

```
line="18/11/1992"
```

Here's the program I wrote.Please pay attention to the regex expressions I've used try to match the above line

```
matchob1 = re.search(r'([\w+\/+])',line)
matchob2 = re.search(r'([\w\/]+)',line)    if matchob1 != None :
    print('The match produced the following info for matchob1 - '+matchob1.group(1))
else:
    print('Sorry no match found in the line : '+str(line)+' for matchob1')
if matchob2 != None :
    print('The match produced the following info for matchob2 - '+matchob2.group(1))
else:
    print('Sorry no match found in the line : '+str(line)+' for matchob2')
```

When I ran the script I got the following output

```
The match produced the following info for matchob2 - 1
The match produced the following info for matchob1 - 18/11/1992
```

I'd like to know whether my understanding is right

The first regex matched only 1 because it looked for \w+ or /+ inside the range [].

The second regex looked for either a word (\w+) or / (/+) followed by any number of occurrences of the pattern within the range []. Is my understanding right or can someone give me a more definitive answer  to help me understand this better ?

Answer (score 0):

`[\w+\/+]` matches a single character from the given list that is, it would match a word character or `+` or `/` . Character class like this `[+++]` or `[+]`
 would match all the literal `+` symbols. So you don't need to repeat the same pattern twice inside a character class.

`[\w\/]+` `+` after the character class would repeat  pattern inside the character class one or more times. So this would match word characters or `/` one or more times. And `()` called capturing groups.

Comment: So inside square brackets, +, ?, * would lose their repetition meaning ?

Answer (score 0):

`The match produced the following info for matchob2 - 1`

Because the character class you mentioned will match only one character as you had not quantified it.So it matched the first character `1`.

Note:`+` inside character class loses special quantifying powers.

`The match produced the following info for matchob1 - 18/11/1992`

Because it cannot match `space` it matches any words with can include `\`.